# How to disable back swipe gesture in react native navigator

Tags: ios, react-native

I am developing one iOS application in react native. I have used Navigator component of react native. When I am pushing user from one screen to another then user can able to pop the screen by swipe on the left edge of the screen. I know how to disable it in native iOS code. However is there any way we can Stop that behavior in React-native app.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it below way,

In React Project I have node_modules folder. There is code for Navigator component at this path,

> /node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/Navigator.js

In that file There is actions for Gestures on Navigations. By removing 'pop' gesture from there stops poping back when slide in from left edge of the screen.

Just replace below code,

```
var GESTURE_ACTIONS = [
  'pop',
  'jumpBack',
  'jumpForward',
];
```

with this code,

```
var GESTURE_ACTIONS = [
  'jumpBack',
  'jumpForward',
];
```

Comment: Very bad practice, you should never modify node_modules by yourself! When you update to a new version all your changes are gone. Not to mention that node_modules are almost always in .gitignore so nobody other than you will see those changes anyway.

Comment: It seems to be a temporary fix and it worked. No other solution worked.

Comment: @patatoma use patch-package to keep your changes in node_modules

Answer (score 13):

Here's great way to do it.

You do not need to hack the node module!!

define a new scene configuration.

```
const NoBackSwipe ={
  ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump,
    gestures: {
      pop: {},
    },
};
```

You can copy whatever SceneConfig they have written, and just set the pop gesture to {}.

This way it will only affect the scene you want it to, and you can still use all the default configs as well.

```
_configureScene(route){
   switch (route.name){
     case 'Foo':
       return NoBackSwipe
       break;
     case 'Bar':
       return Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump
       break;
   }
};
```

The normal HorizontalSwipeJump still has a backswipe, and the custom NoBackSwipe is not allowing back swiping...

```
<Navigator 
 ...other props...
 configureScene={ this._configureScene }
/>
```

boom.

Comment: This worked in the iOS simulator, but not on my Android device.

Comment: What version RN?  This solution works on my Android simulator, RN v 0.28

Comment: I'm running RN 0.29.1.

Comment: I'm now running on Android devices with this solution working for me....

Comment: Excelent answer, this is the only that works for me ;)

Comment: "define a new scene configuration." Where would would do this? Like, where can you define a constant in react-native?

Answer (score 0):

The scene configs are objects with lots of overridable properties in them. If you want to start with FloatFromBottom and disable gestures, you can do this:

```
configureScene={() => ({
  ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom,
  gestures: {}, // or null
})
```

The component should unmount when dismissing with a pop gesture.

Comment: Tried to add gestures : null / gesture : {}, but it does not working for me.