# How enable or disable swipe back in react-native with redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, back

i want be able to `enable` or `disable` this action:

[image]

> This works perfect in react-native without redux, but when i add redux this action not works and come back again like the gif

I'm following [this links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051140/how-to-disable-back-swipe-gesture-in-react-native-navigator) but in this cases, this works with `Navigator` but i'm not using this prop. i'm using `NavigationExperimental`.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable gestures in NavigationExperimental CardStack, use it like this:

```
render () {
  <CardStack
    navigationState={navigationState}
    ... other properties
    enableGestures={false}
  />
}
```

For more info (for RN 0.40) see sources [NavigationCardStack.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.40-stable/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCardStack.js#L155)